# Relationship between absolute magnitude of a star and its luminosity?

Tags: astrophysics

- Why does this relationship involves the absolute magnitude of the sun and its luminosity?
- How to derive an expression relating the absolute magnitude of a star to its luminosity?

So according to the magnitude equation, $$m - M = 2.5\log\left(\frac{d^2}{d_0^2}\right)$$ 
$$\Rightarrow M = m - 2.5\log\left(\frac{d^2}{d_0^2}\right)\ \ (eq1)$$

and Luminosity is $$L = 4\pi(d^2) \times f$$
 $$\Rightarrow d^2 = \frac{L}{4\pi \times f}\ \ (eq2)$$

Plugging eq2 to eq1 would have seem reasonable, but how is absolute magnitude of the sun and its luminosity used?

Comment: It's only used because we compare other star's luminosity to the Sun. In theory, you could measure luminosity in watts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity tells us the Sun's total brightness is 3.846×10^26 watts), but it's the same reason we use light years and astronomical units: to avoid numbers from getting too large.

Comment: This site has TeX enabled. You can format your equations using TeX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are specifically talking about absolute *visual* magnitude; how bright an object would appear to our eyes if the object were 10 parsecs away from us. However, you must remember that stars emit a wide spectrum of light — much of it isn't visible to the naked eye.

Luminosity is a measure of the total amount of energy given off by a star (usually as light) in a certain amount of time. Thus, luminosity includes both visible light and invisible light emitted by a star. So there isn't a precise conversion between luminosity and absolute visual magnitude, although there is an approximation we can do.

Absolute *bolometric* magnitude is an analogous magnitude system considering all the energy emitted by the star. The formula relating absolute bolometric magnitude with luminosity is as follows:
$$L_\text{star} = L_0 10^{-0.4 M_\text{Bol}}$$

where $L_\text{star}$ is the star's luminosity, $M_{\text{Bol}}$ is the bolometric magnitude of the star, and $L_{0}$ is the zero-point luminosity (the luminosity of a star with $M_{\text{Bol}} = 0$) arbitrarily defined as $L_{0}=3.0128×10^{28}$ watts by the [IAU](http://www.iau.org/news/announcements/detail/ann15023/). We can approximately convert between the two magnitudes via a [bolometric correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometric_correction):
$$M_{\text{bol}}\approx M_V + BC$$
The bolometric correction term $BC$ is empirically determined for the spectral class and evolutionary stage (although it can be modeled; see [Torres (2010)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3913v1)). A table of values is given on the Wikipedia page.

The idea is that stars of the same spectral class and evolutionary stage have a similar distribution of wavelengths, so the discrepancy between all emitted wavelengths ($M_{\text{bol}}$) and visible wavelengths ($M_V$) should be similar.

Thus, the conversion between luminosity and absolute visual magnitude is approximately
$$L_\text{star} \approx L_0 10^{-0.4 (M_V + BC)}$$
Of course, this is only an approximation, but it can give us a pretty decent idea of what to expect. Trying it on [9 Pegasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9_Pegasi), I predicted it would be around $1000 L_\odot$, which is still in the ballpark of the actual value $1950 L_\odot$. Mind you, the approximation would be better suited for less extreme stars than 9 Pegasi.