# How do you convert an observed magnitude to a flux?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

For a series of supernovae I have the observed magnitude and I want to convert these values to flux.

I understand that I need to apply:

$m - M_r = -2.5\log_{10} \frac{F}{F_r}$

where $M_r$ is a 'reference magnitude' with corresponding known 'reference flux'.

What exactly should I use as my reference values?

Comment: Very similar: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13709/relationship-between-absolute-magnitude-of-a-star-and-its-luminosity/

Comment: Cheers buddy!!!!

Comment: @SirCumference Yet that original question does not use the term flux, which others may search for as a key term. Perhaps an answer is worthwhile here.

Comment: As I understand the question, it sounds backwards. Usually one takes the flux measurements and uses a reference to determine the magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

The reference magnitude and flux really depends on what filter (i.e. range of wavelengths) the observation was made at (e.g., see the [UBV system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBV_photometric_system), or a more complete set of photometric passbands [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_system)). If you know the filter, and it is in one of the common ultraviolet, optical, or near infrared filters, then [this website](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~martini/usefuldata.html) and [this website](https://archive.is/20121204144725/http://www.astro.utoronto.ca/~patton/astro/mags.html#conversions#conversions) provide useful reference fluxes. Using the common [AB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AB_magnitude) magnitude system then a source with a measured magnitude of zero in any band by definition has a reference flux of 3631 Jy (where 1 [Jansky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansky) = 10<sup>-26</sup> W Hz<sup>-1</sup> m<sup>-2</sup>).