convert magnitude to flux
I have depths for my bands as ,
depths = {
    'F115W': 28.85,
    'F150W': 28.6,
    'F200W': 28.8,
    'F277W': 29.2,
    'F356W': 29.3,
    'F410M': 28.5,
    'F444W': 28.85
}

It is in units of magnitude.
How can I convert it into units of nJy. Which formula should I choose?
(My zeropoint magnitude is 28.08)

Does the answer to this question help? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23346/how-do-you-convert-an-observed-magnitude-to-a-flux
